# Ideal project directory structure for web application using Grunt with npm, bundler and composer

Tags: php, bundler, npm, gruntjs, composer-php

I've got a project set up for a web application using Grunt to automate build tasks. I'm using SASS and Compass as well as Composer to manage PHP dependencies. Currently I have a folder structure which looks like this:

```
-project
 |-build
 |-node_modules
 |-src
 | |-composer.json
 |Gemfile
 |Gruntfile.js
 |package.json
```

This way all of my dependencies for Grunt are configured in package.json and managed by npm, the dependencies for SASS and Compass are configured in the Gemfile and managed by bundler and the dependencies for PHP are configured in composer.json and managed by Composer. Grunt copies over files from the src folder to build during a build, as well as generating/compressing CSS from SASS and minifying js.

I'm wondering if there's a better folder structure for dealing with this as I'd prefer to be able to run all the initial working environment setup from the project root, rather than having to run composer from within src. At the moment I'm keeping it in src in order to generate the autoload path correctly, otherwise it treats the project root as the web root.

**Update:**

Apologies for the unaccept and for the insufficient explanation. To help clarify below is the content of my `composer.json` now that it has been moved to the project root, the issue is not with vendor files but with using composer to create an autoloader for project files:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "src/vendor"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.4.*",
        "zendframework/zend-json": "2.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Project\\": "src/include/"}
    }
}
```

Which outputs the following `autoload_namespaces.php` file inside `vendor/composer`

```
// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname(dirname($vendorDir));

return array(
    'Zend\\Stdlib\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zend-stdlib'),
    'Zend\\Json\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zend-json'),
    'Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/event-dispatcher'),
    'Guzzle\\Tests' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzle/guzzle/tests'),
    'Guzzle' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzle/guzzle/src'),
    'Project\\' => array($baseDir . '/src/include'),
    'Aws' => array($vendorDir . '/aws/aws-sdk-php/src'),
);
```

Having the `$vendorDir` look two levels up with the double `dirname` call is ok, but the `$baseDir` is now pointing to the level above `src`, which is now explicity hardcoded into the autoloader for `Project`. I suspect the only way to solve this is to move `composer.json` back into the `src` folder, or by writing a build script to rewrite this file, which seems nasty. Any alternatives?

Comment: I can't see anything nasty here. The autoloading works, I suppose. As long as you are not splitting your project into parts when deploying, it, or do nasty symlink/root directory stuff, it should continue working. The `$basedir` declaration is in sync with the position of `composer.json`, because from that point on you say there should be a folder `src` containing a folder `include` which contains class files for `Project` namespace - as stated in your autoload description in `composer.json`. Perfect. If you'd ever change that path name, you'll change the autoloading, too - or it breaks.

Comment: Yes that's the problem really. When deploying I don't want the files to live inside `src`, that's just for local testing. When I run grunt, it copies the contents of `src` into `build` and it's from here I do a deploy, without renaming the folder on the server to `src` I think I'll have to move `composer.json` back inside `src`

Comment: I think you should execute `composer install` when the files are inside `build`. And yes, that means you'd have to have `composer.json` and `.lock` inside `src`.

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing that and I like the idea. Thanks! Can you amend your original answer (or add another if your prefer) and I'll reaccept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be forced to put composer.json anywhere else than the project root, but your reason to do so is barely explained. How did you configure your autoloading? You could simply add `src/` to the autoloading path and move composer one level up - and subsequently change the path to `vendor/autoload.php` to be one directory level deeper than now.

**Update**

Based on the new information, you do split your project up during deployment, and the contents of the original `src` folder is copied/morphed/moved to a build folder.

I'd suggest to run `composer install` on the final build folder before pushing the files live. That means you need to copy the `composer.json` and most importantly `composer.lock` files into that build folder, and for reasons of symmetry, these files should reside inside `src` like you started, and then also copied.

Comment: I did have it set up like that before. My issue with doing so is that when composer generates the autoloader - around line 27 of `vendor/composer/autoload_real.php` - it outputs `$baseDir = dirname(dirname($vendorDir));` I was concerned that the nested dirname function call could be a problem when deployed on the production server, but I guess this would be ok actually

Comment: Yes, that one works perfectly and does exactly what one would expect: Strip the "current" filename twice from the inner parameter, which is basically the same as doing a relative path of "../..".

Comment: I've just reminded of why I asked the question in the first place. Having `composer.json` at the project root will only working assuming I upload the `src` folder to the live server as is. I am using Composer to build an autoloader to the project code and when at the top level directory the path to this code in `composer.json` contains the `src` directory, which is therefore copied into `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php`. This is definitely not what I want for the dev and live servers as the contents of the src folder are what should be uploaded, not the folder as a whole.

Comment: Then please update your question, and I can update my answer after that.